# JAVA: Attach a listener to interface implementations

Tags: java

I have an existing interface:

```
public interface ActionInterface<T> {
  Result<T> execute();
}
```

and example implementation

```
public class MyAction<T> implements ActionInterface<T> {
  @Override public Result<T> execute() {
    file.write(this.property);
    return Result();
  }
}
```

I would like to listen for calls on .execute and call `log.debug(obj.property)` whenever it gets called.
What is the best way to get this done?

Please, notice there are likely more implementations of the interface - I'd like to listen for all of them

Comment: You could use an `@Interceptor` but how are you planning on knowing beforehand which property that is?
Maybe use an abstract `getProperty()` in the interface, that way it will be easier for you to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

1. Use some aspect oriented programming library, like AspectJ, or
2. Implement template pattern.

If it is only for a logging purpose, IMHO the first one is the way to go.

For **2)**, you could use an abstract class instead of an interface:

```
public abstract class ActionInterface<T> {
  public Result<T> execute() {
    //obtain property value via reflection or similar - it depends on the use case, it could be included in base class
    log.debug(property);
    return doExecute();
  }

  protected abstract Result<T> doExecute();
}
```

Comment: If I understand that second option correctly - we need to modify every existing implementation to call ActionInterface method?

Comment: Nope. Client invokes execute() method. And this calls `doExecute`, that is method that every concrete class should implement.